# filter a resultset in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

i've a IEnumerable View.this view page(cshtml) comtains a model data and some data of a form.it listed all the data of my model from database. i want to filter those data by multiple filter options such as filter by city,area,floor,road no e.t.c all those filter is in my form field.My action like this:

```
                                                                                            [HttpPost]
  public ViewResult SearchPost()
      {

        var posts =db.posts.Include("user").ToList();

        if (Request.Form["searchString"] != null)
        {
           posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.area   
           ==Request .Form["searchString"]).ToList();                      
        }
         if (Request.Form["searchString2"] != null)
        {
            posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.city 
            ==Request.Form["searchString2"]).ToList();
        }
          if (Request.Form["searchString3"] != null)
        {
            posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.floor 
            ==Request.Form["searchString3"]).ToList();
        }


        return View(posts);
       }
```

My View page:

```
   @using (Html.BeginForm()){   
     <p> Area: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") 
     <p> City: @Html.TextBox("SearchString2") 
     <p> Floor: @Html.TextBox("SearchString3") 
     <input type="submit" value="Filter" /></p>
    }


   >.....list of Model Data
```

my all filter options is optional. one or multiple filter option may be select or none of them may be select. it gives Error **Range Variable posts** i want to filter my resultset in each if condition block. Is it possible ??? if possible then please give me some ideas..... Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you be more specific with the error message?

Answer (score 0):

It's always a good idea to check for null && Any() on results before running your query.  Filter 1 and/or 2 might exclude all you results.

```
if (Request.Form["searchString"] != null)          
{
    if ((posts!=null) && (posts.Any()))
         {
                posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.area
                ==Request .Form["searchString"]).ToList();                                
         }
}           
if (Request.Form["searchString2"] != null)          
{              
    if ((posts!=null) && (posts.Any()))   
         {
                posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.area
                ==Request .Form["searchString2"]).ToList();                                
         }
}            
if (Request.Form["searchString3"] != null)          
{
    if ((posts!=null) && (posts.Any()))   
         {
                posts = (from posts in db.posts where posts.area
                ==Request .Form["searchString3"]).ToList();                                
         }
}
```

Comment: it's gives the error: Range Variable 'posts' conflicts with a previous declaration of posts. i think this error only for Var posts..

Comment: I see....then I would rename your var to something else.  Maybe it's struggling with that.

Comment: you don't need to type posts.  var figures it out for you based on the right side of the equation.  However, it looks like it would be something like IList<posts>

Comment: have you renamed posts to posts1 just to see what would happen